# Simple Conversion Of String To UTF-8 in Ruby 1.8

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

I know that in Ruby 1.9 you can easily re-encode a string like this.

```
s = s.encode('UTF-8')
```

What is the equivalent in Ruby 1.8? What require lines does it need.

All the tutorials I have seen are needlessly complicated and I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Sorry that's the tired talking - corrected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

James Edward Gray II has a [detailed collections of posts](http://graysoftinc.com/character-encodings/understanding-m17n-multilingualization) dealing with encoding and character set issues in Ruby 1.8.  The post entitled [Encoding Conversion with iconv](http://graysoftinc.com/character-encodings/encoding-conversion-with-iconv) contains detailed information.

Summary: the `iconv` gem does all the work of converting encodings. Make sure it's installed with:

```
gem install iconv
```

Now, you need to know what encoding your string is *currently* in as Ruby 1.8 treats Strings as an array of bytes (with no intrinsic encoding.)  For example, say your string was in latin1 and you wanted to convert it to utf-8

```
require 'iconv'

string_in_utf8_encoding = Iconv.conv("UTF8", "LATIN1", string_in_latin1_encoding)
```

The order of arguments is:

1. Target encoding
2. Source encoding
3. String to convert

Comment: What can I do if I am not sure of the encoding for the initial string? Is there any way of detecting it?

Comment: In general? No. If the incoming encoding possibilities is limited, you _might_ be able to use some sort of heuristic, but it would not be completely accurate or reliable (becoming more unreliable as the number of possible encodings increased.)

Comment: Cheers. I guess because it is input from an SQL field I can assume it is this type of character encoding.

Comment: That's a good assumption if you control the database (or at least know who does control it.) Please mark the answer as the accepted answer if you found it helpful. Thanks.

Comment: +1 looks like the links to the grayproductions blog are dead. I could not find a good replacement...