# ruby incorrect method behavior (possible depending charset)

Tags: ruby, whitespace, strip

I got weird behavior from ruby (in irb):

```
irb(main):002:0> pp "    LS 600"
"\302\240\302\240\302\240\302\240LS 600"

irb(main):003:0> pp "    LS 600".strip
"\302\240\302\240\302\240\302\240LS 600"
```

That means (for those, who don't understand) that `strip` method does not affect this string at all, same with `gsub('/\s+/', '')`

How can I strip that string (I got it while parsing Internet page)?

Comment: which ruby version do you use?

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-linux]

Now I am using `gsub('/\302\240/', '')` for replacing, is it only way?

Comment: seams like your string is not in the right encoding.
try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663513/simple-conversion-of-string-to-utf-8-in-ruby-1-8

Comment: Okay, I will keep that in my mind, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string `"\302\240"` is a UTF-8 encoded string (`C2 A0`) for Unicode code point `A0`, which represents a non breaking space character. There are many other Unicode space characters. Unfortunately the `String#strip` method removes none of these.

If you use Ruby 1.9.2, then you can solve this in the following way:

```
# Ruby 1.9.2 only.
# Remove any whitespace-like characters from beginning/end.
"\302\240\302\240LS 600".gsub(/^\p{Space}+|\p{Space}+$/, "")
```

In Ruby 1.8.7 support for Unicode is not as good. You might be successful if you can depend on Rails's `ActiveSupport::Multibyte`. This has the advantage of getting a working `strip` method for free. Install ActiveSupport with `gem install activesupport` and then try this:

```
# Ruby 1.8.7/1.9.2.
$KCODE = "u"
require "rubygems"
require "active_support/core_ext/string/multibyte"

# Remove any whitespace-like characters from beginning/end.
"\302\240\302\240LS 600".mb_chars.strip.to_s
```